# Detail formatter error, Java Eclipse Indigo SR1

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-indigo

This question refers to using Eclipse Indigo SR1 on Windows 7 to write Java code. I've declared an array of objects (an array of IloNumExpr, I'm writing some CPLEX optimization code, but I don't think that matters). After declaring them (putting a breakpoint on the next line), when I mouse over the array of IloNumExpr in the debugger, I see the message

```
Detail formatter error: 
  An exception occurred: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

but when I look at individual elements in the array, they are all null, and when I loop through them and assign each of them, I don't get any kind of error at all. After they're assigned, Eclipse still tells me the same detail formatter error, but every element has been assigned as I expect it to be, and when I pass this array to other methods everything works as I expect.

What does this mean? Should I be concerned?

Answer (score 1):

Error states that it comes from Detail Formatter (`Window/Preferences/Java/Debug/Detail Formatters` or right click in `Variables` view on an array variable and choose `Edit Detail Formatter`).

You can remove or disable formatters that you don't want to use longer.

Answering your main question:
This error means only that detail formatter ends with an error instead of producing output to be printed.
Nothing to be worried about.

Answer (score 0):

I got this message too.
At first I used:

```
this.arr = Arrays.copyOfRange(arr,0,counter);
```

`this.arr` was `null`, so it helped when I added:

```
this.arr = new String[counter];
this.arr = Arrays.copyOfRange(arr,0,counter);
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a tour on how to ask questions properly. If you want to add some more information to your question please edit the question instead of adding an answer. And: Please paste only minimal, but complete code. In your example nobody can know what "counter" or "arr" means.